# Is there an idiomatic way to do where(params[:foo] || '*') in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

If `params[:foo]` is sent, then filter:

```
@submissions = Submission.where(foo: params[:foo] )
                         .order("#{params[:sort]} #{ params[:direction]}" )
```

If not, then

```
 @submissions = Submission.order("#{params[:sort]} #{ params[:direction]}" )
```

What is an idiomatic way to do this?

Is it possible to use a wildcard: `params[:foo] || '*'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of searching for a wildcard, I think you should just separate the `where` call as follows:

```
@submissions = Submission.order("#{params[:sort]} #{ params[:direction]}")
@submissions = @submissions.where(foo: params[:foo]) if params[:foo]
```

This will execute the `where` method updating `@submissions` relation only if `params[:foo]` is present.

A wildcard such as `%` may be used with sql `like` operator.  However, why run the extra where if you want all the records?

Comment: How do you mean by "run the extra where"?

Comment: When you have `where("foo like '%'")`, this will execute the where clause.  Also, I hope you already have an index defined on this `foo` column.

Comment: You can chain `where`s -- they do not get evaluated (i.e., the call to the DB is not made) until needed, so you can add `.where(...)` clauses on new lines -- which is useful for doing conditional `where`s. 

The pattern vee has here is what I've used in the past and is a good pattern.

Comment: @vee - OK, I see. I came up with the same solution, but it does not seem very eloquent to me...